HLS stream Key how to read it
hi everyone anyone know how to read this file this key from Hls video I need a way to read or open this to show me dec_key
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10boR4jhRakCcISTcFbQEI2CP-TyxOCQH/view?usp=sharing
It's only V11 There's also v12 which needs to decrypt ts header
someone give me the key but I don't know how to use it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
